# merging array elements in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

Suppose `x` is an array `[x1, x2, x3, x4, x5]` and we want to merge `x2` and `x4`. This is done by putting their sum in the array and removing `x2` and `x4` from the array. The output array should look like this: `[x1, x2+x4, x3, x5]`.

Here is one way of doing this in Matlab:

```
tmp = x(2) + x(4);
x(2) = tmp;
x(4) = tmp;
[m,n] = unique(x,'first'); 
x(sort(n))
```

This method works as long as there are no duplicates in the array. Is there any clever Matlab way of doing this for any `x` without resorting to loops and shifting of array elements after merging values ?

Comment: In general the input is an array x and the target indices i, j which are to be merged.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to transform this

```
x = [x(1) x(2) x(3) ... x(i)... x(j)... x(n)]
```

into this

```
x = [x(1) x(2) x(3) ... x(i)+x(j) ... **... x(n)]
```

where ** is empty and the new x is n-1 elements long, then you should do:

```
x(i) = x(i)+x(j);
x(j) = [];
```

no tmp, no sort nor unique.

Comment: Yes, but the length of x would still be n. If I need an array of length n-1, I need to shift all the elements from x(j+1):x(n) to the left and cutoff the last index after shifting. Coming to think of it, doing this won't be that expensive after all...